# Show DIV only when url has specific query parameter string jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show the hidden `div` only when the specific url have specific value, like below:

```
var url = window.location.search;
if (url.match("Test Value")) {
    $(".testdiv").show();
}
else if (url.match("Some Text")){
    $(".textdiv").show();
}
```

Not sure if I am trying the correct way and if the none of the string matching, its showing error, what appproach should I try here?

Comment: `elseif` ? Is this correct?

Comment: window.location.search will give you a query string. So, we'll have to decode any url-encoded characters (such as spaces) before we attempt to match the string.

Comment: should be `else if`

Comment: corrected else if

Comment: This looks like you are just trying to see if a query string element is set. I created a little plugin for this and posted to code reviews, maybe you could leverage that instead of doing RegEx matches on the raw query string. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196926/extending-window-location-give-access-to-query-string-elements

Comment: Yes,  I just want to see if spcific query string is available then show div, just dont want to write long lines of code for this :)

Comment: If you add that code I linked to somewhere before you call this code you can just use `window.location.query.myValue` instead of `window.location.search.match("myValue")`

Comment: Yes, correct, much easier, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

```
new URL(location).searchParams.get('nameOfQueryStringParam')
```

Example:

```js
const param = new URL('http://example.com?x=1&y=2').searchParams
console.log(param.get('x')) // 1
console.log(param.get('y')) // 2
console.log(param.get('z')) // null
```

Then, use it for your purpose like ..

```
param.get('x') ? $('#div1').show() : $('#div2').show()
```

Comment: This will work on every browser except IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: True, works on modern browsers only. So works on Edge, not IE.

Comment: Based on OPs requirements this could still very well be the correct answer.